# google+ page vs profile

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an Asp.net webpage where I would like to display google plus information of the users. The google plus IDs are stored in a database. Is there a way (javascript/C#/VB) to determine if a google plus ID is related to a page or a profile? because I have to include different g:plus codes for them. I searched the google developers page but couldn't find anything related to this. Thanx folks!

Answer (score 1):

I just got figured it out how to do this. Maybe someone will face this problem, so here is the answer. There is the REST API's [people get method](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get). If the userId that you target is that of a Google+ page, there will be an **objectType** attribute with a value of page.  You can see this in action [here](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=people.get&userId=116852994107721644038).  Just submit the query and look at the result response. You need an api key for your requests, this key has a limitation of approx. 10000 request/day. [Here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) you can registrate and obtain the api key.